# Making HTTP post requests on Spark usign foreachPartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, httprequest

Need some help to understand the behaviour of the below in Spark (using Scala and Databricks)

I have some dataframe (reading from S3 if that matters), and would send that data by making HTTP post requests in batches of 1000 (at most). So I repartitioned the dataframe to make sure each partition has no more than 1000 records. Also, created a json column for each line (so I need only to put them in an array later on)

The trouble is on the making the requests. I created the following a Serializable class using the following code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row}
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

object postObject extends Serializable{
  val client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
  val post = new HttpPost("https://my-cool-api-endpoint")
  post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json")
  def makeHttpCall(row: Iterator[Row]) = {
      val json_str = """{"people": [""" + row.toSeq.map(x => x.getAs[String]("json")).mkString(",") + "]}"      
      post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json_str))
      val response = client.execute(post)
      val entity = response.getEntity()
      println(Seq(response.getStatusLine.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusLine.getReasonPhrase()))
      println(IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent()))
  }
}
```

Now when I try the following:

```
postObject.makeHttpCall(data.head(2).toIterator)
```

It works like a charm. The requests go through, there is some output on the screen, and my API gets that data.

But when I try to put it in the foreachPartition:

```
data.foreachPartition { x => 
  postObject.makeHttpCall(x)
}
```

Nothing happens. No output on screen, nothing arrives in my API. If I try to rerun it, almost all stages just skips. I believe, for any reason, it is just lazy evaluating my requests, but not actually performing it. I don't understand why, and how to force it.

Comment: For me your code runs fine. The difference between your two code snippets is that the first one runs on the driver and the second one runs on each executor. Did you include the http client libraries in your executors' classpath?

Comment: @werner I'm using Databricks for this, so yes, I believe the executors share the same classpath as the driver (or am I wrong?). Also, would't it throw an error if that was the case?

Comment: No idea how databricks works here. I was using a standalone cluster. I guess you already checked the executor logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postObject` has 2 fields: `client` and `post` which has to be serialized.

I'm not sure that `client` is serialized properly. `post` object is potentially mutated from several partitions (on the same worker). So many things could go wrong here.

I propose tryng removing `postObject` and inlining its body into `foreachPartition` directly.

Addition:

Tried to run it myself:

```
sc.parallelize((1 to 10).toList).foreachPartition(row => {
        val client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
        val post = new HttpPost("https://google.com")
        post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json")
        val json_str = """{"people": [""" + row.toSeq.map(x => x.toString).mkString(",") + "]}"
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json_str))
        val response = client.execute(post)
        val entity = response.getEntity()
        println(Seq(response.getStatusLine.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusLine.getReasonPhrase()))
        println(IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent()))
      })
```

Ran it both locally and in cluster. 
It completes successfully and prints 405 errors to worker logs.
So requests definitely hit the server.

`foreachPartition` returns nothing as the result. To debug your issue you can change it to `mapPartitions`:

```
val responseCodes = sc.parallelize((1 to 10).toList).mapPartitions(row => {
        val client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
        val post = new HttpPost("https://google.com")
        post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json")
        val json_str = """{"people": [""" + row.toSeq.map(x => x.toString).mkString(",") + "]}"
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json_str))
        val response = client.execute(post)
        val entity = response.getEntity()
        println(Seq(response.getStatusLine.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusLine.getReasonPhrase()))
        println(IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent()))
        Iterator.single(response.getStatusLine.getStatusCode)
      }).collect()

println(responseCodes.mkString(", "))
```

This code returns the list of response codes so you can analyze it. 
For me it prints `405, 405` as expected.

Comment: Hmm, why wouldn't the client being properly serialized? The object extends Serializable, and it is not throwing any errors (if I don't extend serialized, than yes, it throws me an error that the task is not serializable).
Anyway, tried putting the code inside the foreachPartition directly, and got the same results. No requests actually made, no errors thrown, no output on console

Comment: I think simpadjo is on to something here. When you use multiple cores per node, then your `HttpClient` will probably be used concurrently by multiple threads, and it is probably not threadsafe. Same for `post`.

Comment: It looks like I was being fooled by the lack of feedback on console (println won't work as I want inside a foreachPartition loop). Now I see some 422s, which explains why I am not seeing anything on the other side. I will do some more messing around, because I believe object approach may work as well, and post back here. Thank you sir

Comment: You are welcome! Objects are not bad themselves, I just wanted to exclude as many problems as possible. But sharing the `post` object has to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without having to find out what exactly is not serializable. If you want to keep the structure of your code, you can make all fields `@transient lazy val`. Also, any call with side effects should be wrapped in a block. For example

```
val post = {
  val httpPost = new HttpPost("https://my-cool-api-endpoint")
  httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json")
  httpPost
}
```

That will delay the initialization of all fields until they are used by the workers. Each worker will have an instance of the object and you will be able to make invoke the `makeHttpCall` method.